# Will my tag be removed from a person's post when I block them?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

I was tagged in a post for scam dating stuff on Facebook and I opened my activity log to manage my tags. I reported the post and block the person who tagged me and when I went to click on the button to remove my tag and it gave an error.

I only use Facebook to connect with friends and participate in family groups, so IDK if my tag removed? I try to keep my profile as secure as possible and I'm freaking out.

Answer (score 1):

I went to the blocked people and tapped unblock which gave a popup and says that unblocking would put the tag back. So I exited the unblock to make sure that the tag stays removed.